# Check if foreign key exists in a database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make an check for my application to see if my table in MySQL contains a foreign key. If so, I want to remove the option to delete the table containing the foreign key. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        require_once 'autoloader.php';

        // cursusManager is verantwoordelijk voor alle person handeling op 
        // de database.
        $cursusManager = new cursusmanager();
        // Aanname dat delete de enige action is op dit scherm

        if(isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "delete") {
            // Aanname dat het id netjes word meegenomen!
            $id = $_GET["id"];
            $cursusManager->delete($id);
        }

        // Haal alle cursussen uit de database om deze verderop te laten zien.
        $cursussen = $cursusManager->getAll();
    ?>

    <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" />

    <h2>Cursussen</h2>
    <!-- simpel gridje, 123 hatsaflats -->
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="gridheader">Naam</div>
        <div class="gridheader">Aantal jaar</div>
        <div class="gridheader">Niveau</div>
        <div class="gridheader gridaction"></div>

        <?php
            // loop door alle personen heen 
            // (in code bovenaan uit database gehaald)
            foreach($cursussen as $cursus) {
                echo "<div class='gridcontent'>$cursus->naam</div>";
                echo "<div class='gridcontent'>$cursus->aantaljaar</div>";
                echo "<div class='gridcontent'>$cursus->niveau</div>";
                echo "<div class='gridcontent gridaction'><a href='index.php?action=delete&id=$cursus->id'>delete</a></div>";
            }

        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the code of my php manager:

```
<?php
/* cursusmanager inherits van mastermanager. Op dit moment bevat de mastermanager
 * alleen nog een database verbinding.
 */
class cursusmanager extends mastermanager {
    public function getById($aId) {
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursus WHERE id = ?");
        $statement->bindValue(1, $aId);

        $statement->execute();

        /* fetchobject haalt het eerste record op uit het statement. PHP
         * maakt hier zelf een object van, dus het model person.php wordt 
         * hier nu niet gebruikt. fetchobject geeft null als er geen records 
         * zijn
         */
        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }

    public function getAll() {
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursus");
        $statement->execute();

        /* fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) haalt ALLE records op uit het statement. PHP
         * maakt hier zelf objecten van, fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) geeft een lege array als 
         * er geen records zijn
         */
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }



    public function delete($aId) {
        throw new Exception("DIT IS DUS NOG NIET GEMAAKT!");
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect to the Information scheme and you can find all the information about the `primary key` and `foreign keys` in this table

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T;
```

you need to be a `ROOT` user to access the information_schema.

USING this table you can find the table, db and whether it has foreign key.